# Exporting an image collection as an asset

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification

Is it possible to export each image from image collection as an asset? If yes how can I improvise this code?

```
    // set cloud threshold
var cloud_thresh = 40;
 
 // Cloud mask function
var cloudMaskL4578 = function(image){

//use add the cloud likelihood band to the image
  
var CloudScore = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image);
  
//isolate the cloud likelihood band
  
var quality = CloudScore.select('cloud');
 
 //get pixels above the threshold
 
 var cloud01 = quality.gt(cloud_thresh);
 
 //create a mask from high likelihood pixels

  var cloudmask = image.mask().and(cloud01.not());

  //mask those pixels from the image

  return image.updateMask(cloudmask);

};

//Image collection for 1990 to 1998 using Landsat 5

var L5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_TOA')

  .filterDate('1990-01-01', '1998-12-30')

  .map(cloudMaskL4578)

  .filterBounds(aoi)

  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 10)

  .map(function(a){

    return a.clip(aoi).set('year', ee.Image(a).date().get('year'));

  });

//Image collection for 1999 to 2013 using Landsat 7

var L7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_TOA")

  .filterDate('1999-01-01', '2013-12-30')

  .map(cloudMaskL4578)

  .filterBounds(aoi)

  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 10)

  .map(function(a){

    return a.clip(aoi).set('year',ee.Image(a).date().get('year'));

  });

//Image collection for 2014 to 2023 using Landsat 8

var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")

  .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2023-12-30')

  .map(cloudMaskL4578)

  .filterBounds(aoi)

  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 10)

  .map(function(a){

    return a.clip(aoi).set('year',ee.Image(a).date().get('year'));

  });

var list= ee.List([]);

var LULClist= ee.List([]);

//Creating trainset

var trainset= ActiveCropland.merge(ForestandHerbaceous).merge(WaterBodies).merge(BuiltupArea);

var bands= ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5'];

for (var a=1990; a<2024; a++){

  if(a<1999){

    var filL5= L5.filterMetadata('year','equals',a).median();

    var Landsat5= filL5.set('year',a)

                       .set('product','L5');

    var trainingL5 = Landsat5.sampleRegions({

  collection: trainset,

  properties: ['Class'],

  scale: 30

});

  var RFclassifierL5=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(trainingL5, 'Class', bands);

  var ClassifiedL5 = Landsat5.classify(RFclassifierL5);

  LULClist= LULClist.add(ClassifiedL5);

    list= list.add(Landsat5) ;

  }



  else if(a>1998 && a<2014) {

    var filL7= L7.filterMetadata('year','equals',a).median();

    var Landsat7= filL7.set('year',a)

                       .set('product','L7');

    var trainingL7 = Landsat7.sampleRegions({

  collection: trainset,

  properties: ['Class'],

  scale: 30

});

  var RFclassifierL7=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(trainingL7, 'Class', bands);

  var ClassifiedL7 = Landsat7.classify(RFclassifierL5);

  LULClist= LULClist.add(ClassifiedL7);                   

    list= list.add(Landsat7) ; 

  }

  else {

    var filL8= L8.filterMetadata('year','equals',a).median();

    var Landsat8= filL8.set('year',a)

                       .set('product','L7');

    var trainingL8 = Landsat8.sampleRegions({

  collection: trainset,

  properties: ['Class'],

  scale: 30

});

  var RFclassifierL8=ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(10).train(trainingL8, 'Class', bands);

  var ClassifiedL8 = Landsat8.classify(RFclassifierL8);

  LULClist= LULClist.add(ClassifiedL8);                   

    list= list.add(Landsat8) ; 

  }

}

print(list);

print(LULClist);

var visParams={

  min: 0,

  max: 0.4,

  bands: ['B5','B4','B3']

};

  var LCparams={

  min:1,

  max:4,

  palette: ['#ffe90e','#4a7c00','#274fff','#e41807' ]

};

var final= ee.ImageCollection(list).map(function(a){

            return a.clip(aoi).set('bands',ee.Image(a).bandNames().length());

});

//Displaying the image collection

//for (var a=1990;a<2024;a++){

  //Map.addLayer(final.filterMetadata('year','equals',a),visParams,'Year'+' '+a, false);

//}

Map.centerObject(aoi,8);

var LULCollection= ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(LULClist);
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export each image in an ImageCollection as an asset in GEE, you can use a [client-side](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) for loop. This method involves iterating through each image in the collection on the client side (i.e., in your browser's JavaScript context) and then initiating an export task for each image to your desired asset location in GEE.

Below is a minimal viable example (MVE) of how to do this:

```
// Define your ImageCollection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-03-01')
  .select('NDVI');

// Define the function to export images
var exportImage = function(image) {
  // Get the image's date for naming purposes
  var date = image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo();
  // Define export task
  var task = Export.image.toAsset({
    image: image,
    description: 'export_to_asset_' + date,
    assetId: date,
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: geometry // Adjust the export region as needed
  });
};

// Convert the ImageCollection to a List to iterate over
var imageList = collection.toList(collection.size());

// Iterate over each image using a client-side for loop
var n = imageList.size().getInfo(); // Get the number of images
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var image = ee.Image(imageList.get(i));
  exportImage(image);
}
```

Comment: Thanks M. Nicolas it worked for me after some editing in your code.